# How to read selected values from DictionaryEntry

Tags: vb.net

I populated a ComboBox using DictionaryEntry values like below.

Now, how to read selected values from the drop down box? `SelectedItem` will not work: it's throwing an error "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'."

```
cboICSOverrideReason.DisplayMember = "Key"
cboICSOverrideReason.ValueMember = "Value"

cboICSOverrideReason.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry("test1", 3))
cboICSOverrideReason.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry("test2", 4))
cboICSOverrideReason.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry("test3", 5))
cboICSOverrideReason.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry("test4", 6))
```

Comment: "I binded combox using DictionaryEntry like below" - your code is not doing any **data-binding**, it's only adding items manually.

Comment: Use `cboICSOverrideReason.SelectedItem`.

Comment: SelectedItem will not work. it's throwing an error "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in a ComboBox are of type Object, so you need to cast it to a DictionaryEntry (because that's what you put in). Furthermore, the DictionaryEntry key and value are also of type Object, so you'll need to convert that as well, like this:

```
myInteger = CInt(DirectCast(cboICSOverrideReason.SelectedItem, DictionaryEntry).Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @dai said, you're not actually binding to a data source. To bind the data you should be doing something like in the .Load event in the code below. The code inlcludes `RemoveHandler` and `AddHandler to stop the`.SelectedIndexChanged` event firing while you're adding the data and to re subscribe the event to your code.

```
Dim mydata As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RemoveHandler cboICSOverrideReason.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cboICSOverrideReason_SelectedIndexChanged
    mydata.Add("test1", 3)
    mydata.Add("test2", 4)
    mydata.Add("test3", 5)
    mydata.Add("test4", 6)
    cboICSOverrideReason.DisplayMember = "Key"
    cboICSOverrideReason.ValueMember = "Value"
    cboICSOverrideReason.DataSource = New BindingSource(mydata, Nothing)
    AddHandler cboICSOverrideReason.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cboICSOverrideReason_SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub



Private Sub cboICSOverrideReason_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboICSOverrideReason.SelectedIndexChanged
    MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(cboICSOverrideReason.SelectedValue, Integer))
End Sub
```

The value returned is always an object, so you'll need to convert it to the appropriate type. So if your value should be an integer, you'll need something like

```
DirectCast(cboICSOverrideReason.SelectedValue, Integer)
```

Comment: I need some thin with DictionaryEntry. Pease read my question.

Comment: I have re-read your question and nowhere in the question do you state that you need something with DictionaryEntry. I would suggest you make that clear in the question. So that people don't waste their free and unpaid time.